# "rollup-plugin-svelte" The following packages did not export their `package.json`

Tags: javascript, import, svelte, swiper.js, rollup

#### I am new in svelte.js. help me please to fix it

Here, when I import the swiper carousel at my .svelte file. it shows me this error which is

> [rollup-plugin-svelte] The following packages did not export their `package.json` file so we could not check the "svelte" field. If you had difficulties importing svelte components from a package, then please contact the author and ask them to export the package.json file.

[Screenshot of Terminal Error. Please check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPzJp.png)

### This is my code file. here  is another component of a carousel slider. but I am seeing this picture when I import the swiper carousel.

```js
<script>
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/svelte";
    import PorfolioCard from "./../components/porfolio-card.svelte";
    import SectionTitle from "./../components/sectionTitle.svelte";
    import "swiper/css";
</script>

<section id="portfolio">
    <SectionTitle title="My Portfolio" subtitle="Visit My Portfolio And Keep your feedback" />

    <div class="mt-4 px-1 px-md-3 px-lg-5">
        <Swiper>
            <SwiperSlide>
                <PorfolioCard />
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
                <PorfolioCard />
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
                <PorfolioCard />
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
                <PorfolioCard />
            </SwiperSlide>

            <SwiperSlide>
                <PorfolioCard />
            </SwiperSlide>
            
        </Swiper>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is not currently a way to silence this warning. There is however an open issue on the GitHub repo regarding it.

https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte/issues/181

**Update:**

Evidently this has since been addressed [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte/commit/66b806b3006dabe0210e99a0a2c7ad41bea42e5d) and the open issue mentioned previously has be closed as a result.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

This error can be safely ignored if it's coming from modules that don't export `svelte` components (eg. `stream`, `util`, `is-odd`; modules that export Javascript files). You can even hide it via overriding `onwarn` in `rollup.config.js`:

```js
const onwarn = (message, warn) => {
    const ignored = {
        PLUGIN_WARNING: ['`package.json`'],
    };
    const ignoredKeys = Object.keys(ignored);
    const ignoredValues = Object.values(ignored);

    for (let i = 0, l = ignoredKeys.length; i < l; ++i) {
        const ignoredKey = ignoredKeys[i];
        const ignoredValue = ignoredValues[i];

        for (const ignoredValuePart of ignoredValue) {
            if (message.code !== ignoredKey
                || !message.toString().includes(ignoredValuePart)) {
                continue;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    warn(message);
};

export default {
    output: {
        format: 'esm',
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public',
    },
    onwarn,
    plugins: [
        // your plugins, eg. `svelte()`
    ],
}
```

#### Mini-explanation

It's emitted because some modules specify the files they're exporting in `package.json` using the [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) field, but they don't include `package.json` itself in the field. This messes with how `rollup-plugin-svelte` identifies modules which export `svelte` components — by reading `package.json` (it can't import what's specifically not exported!). [Here](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte#pkgsvelte)'s some more  technical explanation on the plugin's Github page, regarding why the plugin does things like that & the benefits of it.

Comment: thanks for your help. but still showing this error...